# PHP/MySQL: Get one row and the next five rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have one row that i can SELECT with the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE upload_id = $upload_id
```

But I also want to get the 5 next rows. Using PHP, how can i do that? Order doesn't matter.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM upload WHERE upload_id >= $upload_ID LIMIT 6`, assuming things are sorted naturally by that upload_id

Comment: which 5 rows? 5 random rows, or 5 rows with the next upload ids?

Comment: How can you on one hand say you want the "NEXT" five rows and then also say "Order doesn't matter". These statements don't jive. What do you actually want? Is there an autoincrementing id here for `upload_id`?

Comment: Ha I didn't read the "order doesn't matter" bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that record and the next 5 ascending upload_ids:

```
SELECT * 
FROM uploads 
WHERE upload_id >= $upload_id
ORDER BY upload_id ASC
LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select * from uploads where upload_id >= $upload_id order by upload_id asc limit 6;
```

You should also really avoid using `select *` and instead specify only the fields you need, even if that is all of the fields. That way if the schema changes in the future you aren't returning redundant data.